# Run an executable file through a batch file which is situated in a remote location

Tags: windows, batch-file

Say, I am in directory **D:\Users\S\Documents\ files\test_batch** and now I want to create a batch file in this directory to run a .exe file named test.exe which is situated in location **D:\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c** . I want to run the test.exe file inside the c folder. How can I do this using batch file? I have tried in the following way but it is not working.

```
cd  D:\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c && test.exe
```

How can i do this?

Comment: replace `cd` by `cd /D`...

Comment: you mean cd/D\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c && test.exe ?@user5411115

Comment: No, `cd /D D:\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c && test.exe`, or even better, `cd /D "D:\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c" & test.exe`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pushd D:\Users\S\Documents\s\examples\c
test.exe
popd
```

The commands 'pushd' and 'popd' are used to maintain a "last in/first out" stack of current directories.

Comment: @user5411115, run the commands one at a time from the cmd prompt and tell us what is happening.  We can't see what you see so telling us it is not working is like saying nothing at all.